# Syntax Error Message from MSR_NUIAPI.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, kinect

My issue is this, every time that I compile my program which includes the MSR_NUIAPI.h, the compiler spits out a missing ';' before the INUIInstance interface declaration. I read this article(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ca/kinectsdknuiapi/thread/01b954d2-4095-4b2b-8713-7b47843d8752) which says that I have to include windows.h file before the MSR_NUIAPI.h, however I already have it included before, and I really doubt that this is an actual syntax mistake. IntelliSense(I'm using VS Studio Ultimate) however says that 'interface' is not defined.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including `#include <ole2.h>` after `#include <windows.h>`.

Also, `MSR_NuiApi.h` was included in the beta distribution and is not part of the v1.0 SDK. Its now just `NuiApi.h`.

[Download Kinect SDK v1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/)